# How to edit image in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

**Use Case**

I'm working on a module of **Image Generation** for client. When client will subscribe our service then we'll provide them a Certificate with their name and other details. I've a blank certificate and at runtime when user will log in to its account then user will get certificate when he'll go into certificate section.

I'm not understanding how can I edit or make changes in image as I'm working on image processing for the first time. I have checked [this](https://github.com/faisal5170/Watermark-In-Images-In-MVC-5/blob/master/AddWatermarkToImages/Controllers/HomeController.cs) tutorial but didn't work for me.

Following code that I have used:

**ASP.NET Core Code**

```
    public ActionResult FetchCertificate()
    {
        string filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\ClientApp\\src\\assets\\img\\Certificate_BLANK.png";
        var filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);

        try
        {
            if (filename == null)
            {

                return null;
            }

            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream))
                {
                    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                    {
                        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
                        Font font = new Font("Arial", 90, FontStyle.Italic, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                        SizeF textSize = new SizeF();
                        textSize = graphics.MeasureString("Name of User", font);
                        Point position = new Point(bitmap.Width - ((int)textSize.Width + 10), bitmap.Height - ((int)textSize.Height + 10));
                        graphics.DrawString("Name of User", font, brush, position);

                        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            bitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Png); 
                            memory.Position = 0;
                            return File(memory.ToArray(), "image/png", filename);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new Logger().write(ex);
        }

        return null;

    }
```

**ReactJS Code:**

```
    async componentDidMount() {
                await this.setState({
                    imageInBlob: this.fetchCertificate()
                })
    }

fetchCertificate = async () => {
        let memId = {
            MemberID: this.state.memberId
        }
        const response = await axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/ImageFetch/FetchCertificate',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data: {}
        });

        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
        return url;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Paper>
                    <Typography
                        className='px-2 py-2'
                        variant='h4'>Certificate</Typography>

                    <img src={this.state.imageInBlob} />
                </Paper>
            </div>
            );
    }
```

I have used ASP.NET core as backend and reactjs for front end. When I run above code I'll not get any error but image is also not displays on page.

Can anyone guide me how can I add text to image at runtime and how can I allow user to download the same edited image in ASP.NET core?

Comment: You might want to indicate in what way that tutorial didn't work for you, and copy relevant non-functional code to your question. It's also unclear how this relates to reactjs at the moment. Are we to conclude that you are trying to perform this image generation client side or server side. if it's client side then you shouldn't include the C# and ASP.NET Core tags since they're irrelevant. If it's server side then you shouldn't include the reactjs tag since it's irrelevant.

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica I have edited the question where you were confused

Comment: I'm afraid I've had to vote to close this question as it's unclear where the issue lies. I've tried to help you resolve that by asking for more information, but you've only responded to one part of my request for more information (the inclusion of the code in the question). Likewise, it's still unclear what part reactjs plays in _this piece of code_.

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica Now check. I tried my best to make the question more clear.

Comment: I'd 1) step through the C# code with the debugger and 2) use the browser debugger to check the network response to see if the image is included. This will allow you to narrow down the focus of your question to where the problem actually exists.

Comment: I've developed a nuget package helps to resize and add text/image watermarks easily, See [demo](http://demo.ziyad.info/en/ImageResize), [repo](https://github.com/LazZiya/ImageResize), [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LazZiya.ImageResize/).

Answer (score 0):

In above ASP.NET Core code, I have made following changes which worked for me.

```
var fileName = "filename.png";
var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "FolderName", fileName);
MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();

string stringToBeAdded = "String to be added in image";

using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(filePath))
{
    using(Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        Font font = new Font("Roboto", 90, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        SizeF textSize = new SizeF();

        textSize = graphics.MeasureString(stringToBeAdded, font);
        Point position = new Point(bitmap.Width/2 - (int)textSize.Width/3, ((bitmap.Height/2)-20));
        graphics.DrawString(stringToBeAdded, font, brush, position);

        bitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Png);
        memory.Position = 0;
        return File(memory.ToArray(), "image/png", fileName);
    }
```